# Converting all Realm Objects to Dictionary at once

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary, realm

I am using Realm and I have an `extension` that I use to convert my Realm model into a `Dictionary` , but I do not know how to convert all my Realm models at once. I want to know how do I convert all the realm Objects at once and in one place, so that I can send that dictionary to a API.
Here are my Realm Object Models and the extension I use:

```
class OrderItemList: Object {

dynamic var dateCreated = NSDate()
let orderItems = List<OrderItem>()
}

class OrderItem: Object {

dynamic var name = " "
dynamic var amount = 0
dynamic var internalUnique = Int()
dynamic var isCompleted = false
}
```

**Extension:**

```
extension Object {
    func toDictionary() -> NSDictionary {
        let properties = self.objectSchema.properties.map { $0.name }
        let dictionary = self.dictionaryWithValuesForKeys(properties)

        let mutabledic = NSMutableDictionary()
        mutabledic.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)

        for prop in self.objectSchema.properties as [Property]! {
            // find lists
            if let nestedObject = self[prop.name] as? Object {
                mutabledic.setValue(nestedObject.toDictionary(), forKey: prop.name)
            } else if let nestedListObject = self[prop.name] as? ListBase {
                var objects = [AnyObject]()
                for index in 0..<nestedListObject._rlmArray.count  {
                    let object = nestedListObject._rlmArray[index] as AnyObject
                    objects.append(object.toDictionary())
                }
                mutabledic.setObject(objects, forKey: prop.name)
            }

        }
        return mutabledic
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no magic bullet for converting a batch of Realm objects to a dictionary. You'll need to query for the objects you want, and then loop through each one to produce a serialized version of it.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
var objectDictionaries = [NSDictionary]()

let allObjects = realm.objects(OrderItemList.self)
for object in allObjects {
    let dictionary = object.toDictionary()
    objectDictionaries.append(dictionary)
}
```

I hope that answered your question!